# Reschedule interview after saying I will be unavailable?

Tags: interviewing

I got a voicemail from an interviewer 2 days ago (because I didn't pick up twice) **asking if I'm available** for an interview the next morning. Unfortunately, I was busy doing work and I had other engagements the next day. I called him up and told him I'm not available. That was the last time I talked to him. It dawned on me that I made a **HUGE** mistake. This was my first interview-call from an employer and I had no idea that when he *Asked if I'm available* it actually meant *"Do you want this job or no?"*.

He didn't leave his email and I've already left him a voicemail. 
SO, should I call him now or will that make me seem naggy? I can't email him because he didn't leave that and I don't want to seem like a creep. I was thinking that waiting too long would make me seem unenthusiastic about the position. Should I call him again? What else can I do?

I really need that job and the application was so long. HELP!!!

EDIT: Sorry Joe I accidentally deleted your answer when trying to reply. After how long should I call again?

Comment: But what if he say that I was planning on rescheduling a interview time? That would make me seem annoying.

Answer (score 1):

> He didn't leave his email and I've already left him a voicemail. SO,
>   should I call him now or will that make me seem naggy?

Yes, this might make you seem naggy, but in this case it doesn't sound like you have a lot of choice.

If you cannot discern an appropriate email thru a Google search, call back now and leave a voicemail. This time, tell him that you don't have his email address, and that he could call you back at his convenience.

It might not matter, but it probably won't hurt.